# How to use Twilio on REST client like Postman

Tags: json, twilio, postman, bulksms

Now I am at Stack Overflow as I could not get a simple answer elsewhere for my problem.

I need to send multiple messages with Twilio using Postman. I need to know the script and procedure how to do it. I would prefer JSON(application/json) under `body>raw`. And I would request if a screencast can be added to it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to send multiple messages using Postman? 
What have you tried so far? The example scripts for using Curl can be easily adapted to using Postman instead https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/messaging/send-messages

Comment: I am sorry, I don't intend to send multiple messages, but to the multiple recipients. I will rephrase my question again. If I am not wrong, in order to send the message using postman, I need to follow the following steps: 
1. Request > Post > URL
2. Authorisation > SID and Auth Token
3. Body > Raw > Select JSON(application/json)
4. The script in the blank box below.

Now I need to know the parameters like To, From, Text, etc and the format for the same.

Sorry if this still doesn't explain my query. Thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 4):

1. Open `Postman`, new tab for a new request
2. Select `POST` from the request type drop-down
3. `Enter request URL`

`https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Messages`

(replace `ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX` with `YOUR_TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID`)

4. Click on `Authorization` tab (it's under the request type drop-down) and then for the `type` select `Basic Auth` and you will see two fields `Username` and `Password`
5. Enter `YOUR_TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID` for `Username` and `YOUR_TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN` for `Password`
6. Next, click on the `Body` tab and make sure `form-data` is selected from the radio buttons. Here you need to enter `Key` `Value` pairs like in the picture below (but replace with your values, `From` must be your Twilio number):

[image]

7. Of course, click on the blue `Send` button

Comment: Thanks a ton for your response. Last question, I need to send the message to multiple recipients, how do I separate the numbers in to column?

Comment: If you're using the studio rest api, instead of body, put Parameters and type json for your variables.